# Post-Commit Hook with Trac

Tags: svn, trac, visualsvn-server

So I followed the instructions of the great post left here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113010/post-commit-hook-with-trac-and-svn and the associated posts mentioned for Trac + VisualSVN on windows.

I have set everything up - and when I run the "post-commit.cmd" - I get no errors at all.

My problem is - that Trac does not update tickets after I submit a commit and I cannot figure out why ? I turned Logging on in Trac - and when I run the post-commit.cmd script from the hooks folder I get the line below, but no tickets update?

Trac[svn_fs] DEBUG: Subversion bindings imported

Does anyone have any ideas how I can somehow figure out why its not updating Tickets from the SVN ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113985/post-commit-hook-with-trac

Answer (score 1):

Please try update to latest VisualSVN Server 2.0.5 and updated [Trac plugin](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/trac/).

Also make sure that PYTHONHOME environment variable points to Python packaged with VisualSVN Server Trac plugin (C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\trac\python by default)